# HTML HOSTED ANDROID APP SUSPENDED BY GOOGLE

Tags: android

2 days ago i made 1 app,the app is based on lyrics of hindi songs.the data of lyrics are stored under an html files.and i host those files on google drive.and i set  the link of index.html in my app...app works perfectly but today i'm uploded my app. and google emailed me that your app suspended for "IP infragment or deceptive behaviour".i neither use any copyrighted things nor any copyrighted images.and i host my data in my privet google drive.

i want to ask you :-

is there any solution for it???
what can i do for upload my app??
is there google have problem with his own google drive service??

i have no information about it what to do?

hope favorable reply from you....

**sorry for my bad english**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about copyright and Google policies.

Comment: lyrics of hindi songs is probably copyrighted.

Comment: thanx eriuzo for answering.but sir i want to know that can i use html webpages which is hosted on my google drive.??can i linked it in my app.??google allow me for upload thats type apps???

Comment: Google does not care where you host that content. If your app shows it and their review process concludes that it's copyright infringement they will remove your app. Lyrics are copyrighted material just as any other written text is. ( see e.g. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2217281/LiveUniverse-Lyrics-site-fined-record-6-6m-copyright-infringement.html for an example )

Comment: thanx zapl,for give me such a valueble informaton now my all doubts are cleared....thnax bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By publishing to the Google Play store, you are agreeing to adhere to the Google Play Store Policies.

Go through their IP Policies from the following link and ensure you adhere their policies.

[Intellectual Property Policies](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2985818?ref_topic=2985713&rd=1)

If you think otherwise, and you want to file an appeal follow the following link

[File an appeal](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981?hl=en)

Comment: thanx for reply VizZy.i just want to ask that "is google playstore supported for upload an app in which html web files are used and hosted in other server such as google drive?????